# ManagedQuery() within fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have following function which i am calling in my oncreate function which extends fragment activity. It shows error on `managedQuery()`. It worked perfect when i was extending my class with Activity. But now i tried this within Fragment it fails. Any suggestions please.

**code**

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
 init_phone_video_grid();
 return rootView;

    }

 private void init_phone_video_grid() {
        System.gc();
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Video.Media._ID, MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE };

        file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "Funtube/UserData/Videos/");

        videocursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, proj, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " LIKE ? ",new String[] {"%"+file.getAbsolutePath().toString()+"%"}, null);

        count = videocursor.getCount();
        videolist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.PhoneVideoList);
        videolist.setAdapter(new VideoAdapter(getApplicationContext()));
        videolist.setOnItemClickListener(videogridlistener);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

`managedQuery`is method of `Activity`,not `Fragment`,so replace

```
videocursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, proj, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " LIKE ? ",new String[] {"%"+file.getAbsolutePath().toString()+"%"}, null);
```

with

```
videocursor = getActivity().managedQuery(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, proj, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " LIKE ? ",new String[] {"%"+file.getAbsolutePath().toString()+"%"}, null);
```

but the method has been deprecated in API 11,Google suggest using [CursorLoader](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) instead,there are some examples about how to use it:

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/load-data-background/setup-loader.html,

http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/12/how-to-use-android-cursorloader.html#.Vnv42Rp96Rs

Comment: I did so, But it stops the application and gives error on function. And also it says that managedQuery function is depreciated.

Comment: yes, the method is deprecated in API level 11. Google suggest Using [CursorLoader](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) instead.

Comment: Can you please provide me code for my work with CursorLoader as i have no idea how to do this.

Comment: there is an example about CursorLoader:http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/load-data-background/setup-loader.html,and here:http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/12/how-to-use-android-cursorloader.html#.Vnv42Rp96Rs

Answer (score 0):

`ManagedQuery` is not a method of a `Fragment`, but from an `Activity`. It is also deprecated, you should use `CursorLoader` instead.

[Android Activity documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Comment: How can i use cursorLoader?

Comment: Please take a look at the documentation for `CursorLoader`: http://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/setup-loader.html